# change jTable model in runtime

Tags: java, jtable

I have a Java form application and I want to change a jTable's tableModel during runtime (on button click)
I'm using the following code:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Execute"); 
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            TableModel newModel = dbHandler.executeQueryToTable(myQuery.getText());
            table.setModel(newModel);
            ((AbstractTableModel) newModel).fireTableDataChanged();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

The problem is that the table isn't changing. I checked  that the model is ok but I think that the table needs to be updated somehow.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We can't debug your code when you only show us one line.

Comment: I added everything that happens when I press the button.

Comment: @user2740785 this is not [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How you declare and initialize your table?

Comment: also what is executeQueryToTable(), what it returns?

Comment: `I think that the table needs to be updated somehow.` - if you have a proper reference to the table that is visible on the frame and if the TableModel contains valid data, then the table will be updated. If not then on of the two conditions above is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Try to temporarily change your code with the code below. If your table updates when the button is clicked, then problem can be your `dbHandler.executeQueryToTable(myQuery.getText())`

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Execute"); 
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        TableModel newModel = new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {{"a", "b"}, {"e", null}},
            new String [] {"Title 1", "Title 2"});

        this.jTable1.setModel(newModel);
        ((AbstractTableModel) newModel).fireTableDataChanged();



    }
});
```

The code above works fine in my test.

Comment: Don't invoke fireTableDataChanged(). It is the job of the TableModel to invoke the appropriate fireXXX() method. However in this case there is no need to fire any event because you are using the setModel() method of the table so the table knows the TableModel has changed already.

Comment: @camickr. Ok. The OP should know about that because that is his code that I just copied.